# JavaFX GridLayout Object Hides Nodes

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, javafx, graphics

How can I get the VBox and Label objects I create, to appear on the same window and in the positions I want?
The label is the title.
The VBox object holds four buttons.

I want to make the VBox Button objects to appear below the title in the window that's created.

With this code, only the Label object "title" is displayed. I can also make the VBox appear, but only if it's column and row parameters are lower or at the same  height as the Label object.

This class is called in my MainClass class to display the main menu.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainMenu extends Stage{
   private Button[] buttArr = {new Button("New Game"),
         new Button("Save Game"),
         new Button("Load Game"),
         new Button("Exit Game")};

   private Label title = new Label("Bandit King");
   private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
   private VBox menuItems = new VBox();

   MainMenu() {
      grid.setHgap(10);
      grid.setVgap(10);
      grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

      menuItems.getChildren().addAll(buttArr);
      menuItems.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
      menuItems.setSpacing(30);

      grid.add(title, 9, 7);
      grid.add(menuItems, 5, 25);


      this.setScene(new Scene(grid, 1600, 900));
      this.setTitle("Bandit King");
      this.show();

      // set title font
      Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("OLDSH.TFF"), 1);
      title.setFont(new Font("OldStyle 1 HPLHS", 100));
      title.getStyleClass().add("title");

      // set New Game Button action
      buttArr[0].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            new Hideout();
         }
      });

      // set Save Game Button action
      buttArr[1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            System.out.println("WIP- save game");
         }
      });

      // set Load Game Button action
      buttArr[2].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            System.out.println("WIP- load game");
         }
      });

      // set Exit Game Button action
      buttArr[3].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
         }
      });

   }
}
```

Here is my MainClass class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainClass extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start (Stage stage) {
      MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();

      stage = mainMenu;

      stage.show();
   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

Here is what is displayed with this code:
[image]

Comment: I didn't see your problem or I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Sedrick My problem is that I want the buttons inside the VBox object to appear underneath the Label title, but I can't seem to get both to appear in the right positions. I want the Label to appear above the menu items, and java is giving me issues. Depending on where I set them in the GridPane sometimes one or the other doesn't display, or they're in the wrong positions.

Comment: try maximizing the window.

Comment: the high col/row values look weird - why not place them "near" each other? Don't understand what it _should_ look like .. also, your code has other issues (don't extend Stage et al, and stage = new Stage is a no-op) so could be your expectations don't fit the layout provided.

Comment: @kleopatra Do you mean "high" as in the number of the row/column, or where it's placed in the window? The buttons are fairly near each other. I want the VBox object to appear. The VBox object has Button objects in it. Those Buttons should appear on the window. That's what it should look like. I will edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: high numbers - as in row 25 when you basically have only 6 rows with controls in them. But that's not the causing the problem: the reason ultimately is related to your slightly crazy setup (create a new stage that shows itself in the constructor) - where you size its scene to 1600,900, that's a) out of the way to notice and b) leads to having the menuItems off the screen. Better to let MainMenu create and configure the content of a scene and then add that content to a stage. Repeating: no reason to subclass Stage!

Comment: @kleopatra Have you tried to run this code yourself? I have been able to dodge the problem by using an ImageView object instead of a Label object. I have had two people say they found now problem with my code, but I keep getting the same problem if I try to use a Label.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication282 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();

        primaryStage = mainMenu;

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I commented out `this.show();` and `new Hideout();` because you didn't post the `Hideout` class.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainMenu extends Stage
{

    private Button[] buttArr = {new Button("New Game"),
        new Button("Save Game"),
        new Button("Load Game"),
        new Button("Exit Game")};

    private Label title = new Label("Bandit King");
    private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    private VBox menuItems = new VBox();

    MainMenu()
    {
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

        menuItems.getChildren().addAll(buttArr);
        menuItems.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        menuItems.setSpacing(30);

        grid.add(title, 9, 7);
        grid.add(menuItems, 5, 25);

        this.setScene(new Scene(grid, 1600, 900));
        this.setTitle("Bandit King");
        // this.show();

        // set title font
        Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("OLDSH.TFF"), 1);
        title.setFont(new Font("OldStyle 1 HPLHS", 100));
        title.getStyleClass().add("title");

        // set New Game Button action
        buttArr[0].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                // new Hideout();
            }
        });

        // set Save Game Button action
        buttArr[1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                System.out.println("WIP- save game");
            }
        });

        // set Load Game Button action
        buttArr[2].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                System.out.println("WIP- load game");
            }
        });

        // set Exit Game Button action
        buttArr[3].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The output from me running your code.

[image]

Comment: I don't get the same result. Are you sure you didn't change anything? I have posted an image of what I get.

Comment: I updated my code and tried maximizing the window. The window maximized, but nothing changed.